# No se refrescan el listado despues de crear o registros vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Estoy haciendo un mantenedor, en donde al crear un registro, desactivo otro con motivo que sea igual y quedando activo el nuevo (queda vigente el nuevo).
Pasa que al crearse, el registro, internamente, si deshabilita y habilita, pero tengo que cerrar la pagina y volver a entrar para que me refresque los cambios.

#### 1. estado inicial

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 2. despues de crear un nuevo registro (acá es donde está el problema)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### 3. luego de cerrar modal y abrir nuevamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy trabajando con vuex.

acá el código

### FormList.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <forms-filter></forms-filter>

    <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        :loading="loading"
        :page="pagination.current_page"
        :items-per-page="pagination.per_page"
        :server-items-length="pagination.total"
        :footer-props="{
                'show-current-page': true,
                'items-per-page-options': [5, 10, 15],
            }"
        @update:page="handlePage"
        @update:items-per-page="handlePerPage"
    >
      <template #[`item.kind`]="{ item }">
        <span v-if="item.kind === 1">{{ $t("Route start") }}</span>
        <span v-else>{{ $t("Route end") }}</span>
      </template>

      <template #[`item.form_detail`]="{ item }">
        <v-chip-group>
          <v-chip
              v-for="detail in item.form_detail"
              :key="detail.id"
              color="primary"
              outlined
              label
              small>
            {{ detail.label }}
          </v-chip>
        </v-chip-group>
      </template>

      <template #[`item.is_active`]="{ item }">
        <v-switch @change="handleActivated(item)"
                  v-model="item.is_active"
                  hide-details="auto"
                  inset
                  dense
                  class="m-0"
        ></v-switch>
      </template>

      <template #[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
        <v-btn icon small @click.stop="handleEdit(item.id)">
          <v-icon small> mdi-pencil</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn icon small color="red" @click.stop="handleDelete(item.id)">
          <v-icon small> mdi-delete</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters, mapActions} from "vuex";
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "FormsList",
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      headers: [
        {
          text: this.$t("Reason"),
          value: "reason.name",
          align: "left",
          sortable: false,
          cellClass: "cell__collapsing",
        },
        {
          text: this.$t("Fields"),
          value: "form_detail",
          align: "left",
          sortable: false,
        },
        {
          text: this.$t("Vigente"),
          value: "is_active",
          align: "left",
          sortable: false,
        },
        {
          text: "",
          value: "actions",
          align: "end",
          sortable: false,
          cellClass: "cell__collapsing",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      items: "forms/items",
      pagination: "forms/pagination",
    }),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations({
      setForm: "forms/SET_ITEM"
    }),
    ...mapActions({
      handleVisible: "forms/toggleVisible",
      fetchItems: "forms/fetchItems",
      updateForm : "forms/updateItem",
    }),
    handlePage(page) {
      this.fetchForms({page});
    },
    handlePerPage(count) {
      this.fetchForms({per_page: count});
    },
    async fetchForms(params) {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log(params)

      await this.fetchItems(params)
          .finally(() => this.loading = false);
    },
    handleShow(id) {
      this.handleVisible({view: "show", id});
    },
    handleEdit(id) {
      this.handleVisible({view: "edit", id});
    },
    handleDelete(id) {
      this.handleVisible({view: "delete", id});
    },
    async handleActivated(item) {
      this.setForm({id: item.id})

      await this.updateForm({
        ...item,
        is_active: item.is_active,
      });

      await this.fetchForms()
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

el js del store

### forms.js

```
export const state = {
    visible: {
        index: false,
        create: false,
        show: false,
        edit: false,
        delete: false,
    },
    items: [],
    item: {
        id: null,
    },
    pagination: {},
    params: {},
};

export const getters = {
    visible: (state) => state.visible,
    items: (state) => state.items,
    item: (state) => state.item,
    pagination: (state) => state.pagination,
    params: (state) => state.params,
};

export const mutations = {
    SET_VISIBLE: (state, {view, status}) => (state.visible[view] = status),
    SET_ITEMS: (state, payload) => (state.items = payload),
    SET_ITEM: (state, payload) => (state.item = payload),
    ADD_ITEM: (state, payload) => state.items.unshift(payload),
    UPDATE_ITEM: (state, payload) => {
        let item = state.items.find((item) => item.id === payload.id);

        if (item === -1) return;

        Object.assign(item, payload);
    },
    REMOVE_ITEM: (state, payload) => {
        let item = state.items.findIndex((item) => item.id === payload);

        if (item === -1) return;

        state.items.splice(item, 1);
    },
    SET_PAGINATION: (state, payload) => (state.pagination = payload),
    SET_PARAMS: (state, payload) => (state.params = payload),
};

export const actions = {
    toggleVisible({commit, state, dispatch}, {view, id}) {
        let status = !state.visible[view];

        if (id && status) commit("SET_ITEM", {id});

        commit("SET_VISIBLE", {view, status});
    },
    configClient({rootGetters}) {
        this.$axios.defaults.baseURL =
            rootGetters["application/settings"].routeApiUrl;
        this.$axios.defaults.headers = {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        };
        this.$axios.defaults.params = {
            token: rootGetters["application/settings"].routeApiToken,
        };
    },
    async fetchItems({commit, state, dispatch}, payload) {
        dispatch("configClient");

        commit("SET_PARAMS", payload);

        return await this.$axios
            .get('/forms', {params: state.params})
            .then((response) => {
                let resource = response.data;

                commit("SET_ITEMS", resource.forms);
                commit("SET_PAGINATION", resource.meta);

                return response;
            })
            .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
    },
    async fetchItem({commit, state, dispatch}) {
        let id = state.item.id;

        dispatch("configClient");

        return await this.$axios
            .get(`/forms/${id}`, {params: this.params})
            .then((response) => {
                let resource = response.data;

                commit("SET_ITEM", resource.form);

                return response;
            })
            .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
    },
    async storeItem({commit, state, dispatch}, payload) {
        dispatch("configClient");

        return await this.$axios
            .post('/forms', payload)
            .then((response) => {
                let resource = response.data;

                commit("ADD_ITEM", resource.form);

                dispatch("fetchItem");

                return response;
            })
            .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
    },
    async updateItem({commit, state, dispatch}, payload) {
        let id = state.item.id;

        dispatch("configClient");

        return await this.$axios
            .put(`/forms/${id}`, payload)
            .then((response) => {
                let resource = response.data;

                commit("UPDATE_ITEM", resource.form);

                dispatch("fetchItem");

                return response;
            })
            .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
    },
    async destroyItem({commit, state, dispatch}) {
        let id = state.item.id;

        dispatch("configClient");

        return await this.$axios
            .delete(`/forms/${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                commit("REMOVE_ITEM", id);

                return response;
            })
            .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error));
    },
    clearParams({commit}) {
        commit("SET_PARAMS", {});
    },
};
```

Espero me puedan echar una mano con esto.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No puedo dar mi veredicto final, pero me parece que el problema está en tus mutaciones, no están cambiando el state como quieres(puedes imprimir el state después de cada mutación para que veas si cambia como quieres), y cuando recargas se lee la data del servidor así que ahí si funciona.

Comment: hice un console.log(state.items); 
y el nuevo form,, se encuentra dentro del state.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la funcion $set para actualizar el arreglo con el que dibujas la lista de la siguiente forma

```
let array = [] // tu arreglo
let indexOfItem = 0 // aqui el indice del item que quieres actualizar
let newData = {} // todo el objeto con la informacion que buscas actualizar

this.$set(array, indexOfItem, newData);
```

Con algo asi pudieras actualizar la informacion de tu arreglo y que se vea reflejado de inmediato

Comment: hola...gracias por comentar.. 
creo que finalmente lo hice con un mutador "SET_DEFAULT", con este modifiqué el state. .. Luego subiré la respuesta definitiva. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

creo que tu problema es que estás usando operaciones tales como `splice` u `Object.assign` que son "in place" es decir la referencia no cambia, para que vue/vuex reconozcan un cambio tenés que asignar un nuevo valor al estado (explícitamente usando `variable = nuevoValor`) y que el nuevo valor no sea la misma referencia que el antiguo valor, intenta lo siguiente:

```js
 ADD_ITEM: (state, payload) => {
  state.items =  [...state.items, payload]; // es importante la asignación al estado (=) como el crear un nuevo array, destructurar un array dentro de otro crea una nueva referencia
 },
    UPDATE_ITEM: (state, payload) => {
        const itemIndex = state.items.findIndex((item) => item.id === payload.id);

        if (item === -1) return;

        state.items[itemIndex] = payload; // asignación (=) y un nuevo object (en este caso payload ya es una nueva referencia) 
    },
    REMOVE_ITEM: (state, payload) => {
        let item = state.items.findIndex((item) => item.id === payload);

        if (item === -1) return;

        // alternativa 1
        const newItems = [...state.items]; // acá se crea un nuevo array
        newItems.splice(item, 1); // el nuevo array se modifica
        state.items = newItems; // se asigna el nuevo array (=)

        // alternativa 2
        /* state.items = state.items.filter((i, index) => index !== item) // filter y map siempre retornan un nuevo array */
    },
```